# SeekBar changes Theme after Spinner item clicked

Tags: android, xml, seekbar

I'm using my own `Spinner` and customized `SeekBar`. On API 23 or more everything work perfect but on Android lower than 22 it total doesn't work.
Tapping a value at the EditText Spinner change value and works like charms, changing Spinner selected value changes the SeekBar theme. 
There is no actions on the Spinner.

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBarVolt"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_seekbar"
    android:thumb="@drawable/custom_seekbar_thumb" />
```

**Before Clicking on Spinner**

[image: Plash 1]

**After Clicking on Spinner**

[image]

Spinner Code :

```
public class FSSpinner extends AppCompatSpinner {

    public FSSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FSSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public FSSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void
    setSelection(int position, boolean animate) {
        boolean sameSelected = position == getSelectedItemPosition();
        super.setSelection(position, animate);
        if (sameSelected) {
            OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener = getOnItemSelectedListener();
            if (onItemSelectedListener != null) {
                onItemSelectedListener.onItemSelected(this, getSelectedView(), position, getSelectedItemId());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void
    setSelection(int position) {
        boolean sameSelected = position == getSelectedItemPosition();
        super.setSelection(position);
        if (sameSelected) {
            OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener = getOnItemSelectedListener();
            if (onItemSelectedListener != null) {
                onItemSelectedListener.onItemSelected(this, getSelectedView(), position, getSelectedItemId());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Seekbar xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle"
            android:tint="#77C344">
            <size android:height="30dp" />
            <solid android:color="#77C344" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%">
            <selector>
                <item
                    android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:state_enabled="false" />
                <item>
                    <shape
                        android:shape="rectangle"
                        android:tint="#77C344">
                        <size android:height="30dp" />
                        <solid android:color="#77C344" />
                    </shape>
                </item>
            </selector>
        </scale>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

---

SeekBarThumb.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:thickness="4dp"
    android:tint="#000"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <solid android:color="#000" />
    <size
        android:width="12dp"
        android:height="32dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing below from **Seekbar.xml**, No need to mention state_enabled here, as you have **only one state**

```
android:state_enabled="false"
```

Comment: sorry but still have the same problem.